# LinkedIn rest API: Retrieve Organization Follower Count error

Tags: linkedin-api

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-09&tabs=http#retrieve-organization-follower-count) we can get the organization follower count with the following call

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:1234567?edgeType=CompanyFollowedByMember
```

This was working until the 1st of September and from then on we get an error.

I can't find anywhere in the documentation that this edgeType was deprecated.
Is this a known issue? If so, do you have a prediction when it will be fixed?

The response of the call

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:1234567?edgeType=CompanyFollowedByMember
```

should be:

```
{
  "firstDegreeSize": 219145
}
```

But instead we get the error

```
{
    "errorDetailType": "com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid param. Please see errorDetails for more information.",
    "errorDetails": {
        "inputErrors": [{
                "description": "ERROR :: /value :: \"CompanyFollowedByMember\" is not an enum symbol",
                "input": {
                    "inputPath": {
                        "fieldPath": "edgeType/value"
                    }
                },
                "code": "FIELD_INVALID"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}.
```

Comment: You may want to check with LinkedIn/Microsoft support since it does match exactly what they have in their documentation (and was working at one point and then suddenly it was broken).

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of edgeType from `CompanyFollowedByMember` to `COMPANY_FOLLOWED_BY_MEMBER`

This worked for me. We also have example in API docs.

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:1234567?edgeType=COMPANY_FOLLOWED_BY_MEMBER
```